# matlab-Adding gaussian noise using pdf

Tags: matlab, gaussian

I am trying to add gaussian noise to an image using the pdf model. I have searched for hours but the only thing I get is either imnoise or a manual code as below:

```
Inoise = Orig_img + (sqrt(variance)*randn(size(Orig_img)) + mean);
```

The pdf for gausssian noise is:

[image: pdf of gaussian]

Any way I can use this to generate noise in an image

Comment: What's the problem with using imnoise?

Comment: I am trying to learn how to add without using built-in commands

Comment: It's better not to use `mean` as a variable name. It's the name of a Matlab function. And you can remove the outer parentheses. Other than that, it's the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only solution (and correct one) found is

```
Inoise = Orig_img + (sqrt(variance)*randn(size(Orig_img)) + mean);
```

pdf are only meant to see the noise shape, pattern etc.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have given is correct. You can do the same with

```
mu    = ...
sigma = ...
im_with_noise = im_original + normrnd(mu,sigma, size(im_original));
```